# Add a simple bone pivot to Rigify rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm in the process of learning rigify and I want to add a simple jaw bone for the mouth, but I don't know how to make a handle for that when generating a rigify rig.

I tried to modify a meta rig (i think its the wolf rig). But it never generates a usable control for the jaw bone. I've attached the blend file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d0Z9MyEa8P2ITISrP-2pJeiC5NbMUiNZ/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add everything from rigify samples. Not sure that exactly you need to add, but I think you can test and select what it more suitable for your needs.

[image]

Comment: I cant find the rigify samples dropdown. I clicked on a rig but its not there.

Comment: @Mike have you searched in edit mode?

Comment: looks like this tab has been renamed to Rigify buttons. I still cant figure it out though. When I add a basic.pivot bone, generate rig, and apply automatic weights it doesn't move the jaw.